# Equivalent of F# StartImmediate

Tags: c#, f#, async-await

Is there a C# equivalent of F#'s `StartImmediate` which can be executed on a `Task`?  I have a situation where I need to await a function sometimes, but other times I just want the method to call back to the UI thread without using `await`.

I want to avoid async void if possible.

Example:

```
public async void DoSomething()
{
    //before runs on UI thread
    await OtherThing();
    //after runs on UI thread
}

public async Task DoSomethingElse()
{
    //before runs on UI thread
    await OtherThing();
    //I want this to run on the UI thread
}

public void CallDoSomething()
{
    DoSomething(); //no need to await, returns to the UI thread to continue execution

    DoSomethingElse();//Doesn't return to the UI thread to continue execution

    DoSomethingElse().???(); // how to return to the UI thread for the async callback?
}
```

In F# this would look like this:

```ml
let CallDoSomething () =

    //more code here

    async {
        //runs on the current thread
        do! OtherThing()
        //runs on the current thread
    } |> Async.StartImmediate

    //code here doesn't wait for the async to finish
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean. It would really help if you could give a concrete example.

Comment: If you want to `await` something if a condition is met then all you need to do is write `if(condition)await task;`  However if that was what you *really* wanted to do, I don't imagine you'd be asking this question, so what am I not understanding?

Comment: @JonSkeet Does that clarify things a bit?

Comment: Not really. What's `CallDoSomething` called from? What do you mean by "returns to the UI thread"? What do you mean by "doesn't return to the UI thread"? Why are you trying to call `Start()` on a task returned by an async method?

Comment: @JonSkeet see Servy's answer for clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, when looking at your code example.  You have an `async` method that return a `Task`.  You're calling that method, and then calling `Start` on the resulting task (without calling `await`).  That will throw an exception at runtime.  The task is already started just by calling the method.  Starting an already running task (or a completed task, if it completed before it returned) will throw an exception.  You can only `Start` a task created using the `Task` constructor, which you're not using.

You also claim, in comments, that you are not in the UI thread when you return after calling `DoSomethingElse`.  That is false.  The code *will* run in the UI thread.

You also imply that the `await` in `DoSomethingElse` won't marshal the callback to the UI thread, but it *will*.  Since it was called from the UI thread, it captured the UI context, and uses it when calling `await`.

So in short, you need to do nothing except remove the call to `Start`.

The one problem you *do* have, if you structure your code like this, is that you will never know if your code errors out, as there is nothing to observe any exceptions.  There are two ways you could address this.  One would be for each of the methods you call in this manor to consider themselves "top level methods" and handle *all* exceptions instead of every throwing any.

The other option would be to store all of the tasks called in this manner and `await Task.WhenAll` those tasks, so you can observe any errors when they all finish.

Comment: Yeah, sloppy on my part with the `Start()`. Ah, so tasks continue in their original thread context even when not awaited?

Comment: Yeah.  :-P Blame android.  Top-level events have return values, so you can't do proper async calls.  You pretty must have to create a new level of top level events.  I want to share this code with iOS and Win 8 though, so the new "top level" events still need to return `Task`.

Comment: @mydogisbox The only way to *not* continue on the original thread would be to `await`, but use `ConfigureAwaitFalse`.  The currently executing thread is simply calling a method.  That method returns a value, in this case, a task.  When a thread is set to execute a method that has two methods in it, it won't just stop executing after the first sub-method.  It has no where else it *could* go except to go and execute the next sub-method.

Comment: Ah, for some reason I thought the task would execute on a new `Thread`. Thanks!

Comment: @mydogisbox A new thread is only created when you explicitly call something to create one.  Generally this would be done through a call to `Task.Run`.  Without that, there *is* no thread other than the UI thread.

Answer (score -2):

Did you try the RunSynchronously() method of the Task class ?

Comment: I want it to run asynchronously, but without halting the execution of the current method.

Comment: Excuse me I misunderstood your question :(

Comment: If you want to get rid of the negative rep, you can just delete your answer.